# Setting a Warning message in the Page.tpl.php file

Tags: theming

I'm trying to set a warning message based on a PHP if statement in my page.tpl.php file. I can get a message out using `$messages` but I cannot using `drupal_set_message()`. Should I be using the latter before page.tpl.php?

The problem is the `$messages` variable comes out as plain text, I'd like to use Drupal's message system if possible:

```
drupal_set_message(t('Don\'t panic!'), 'warning');
$messages = t('Don\'t panic!');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use Drupal's message system, and you want to do this at the theme-level, as opposed to writing a module, you would enter the code

```
drupal_set_message(t('Don\'t panic!'), 'warning');
```

into your theme's template.php file as a preprocess function.  For instance, if you wanted to display this message on all content of the type 'page'

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 if ($variables['node']->type = 'page') {
  drupal_set_message(t('Don\'t panic!'), 'warning');
 } 
}
```

It should then automatically show up in the $messages area whenever someone visits a 'page' content type.

Note: You might also need to flush your theme cache after making these changes.